# OpenMP omp_get_wtime g++ 32bits

Tags: c++, gcc, openmp

For measuring the time of some parts of a program I want to use the `omp_get_wtime()` function from OpenMP. I can compile the project only in 32bits (with the `-m32` gcc option). And I get those errors:

```
libgomp.a(time.o): In function 'gomp_ialias_omp_get_wtick':
  undefined reference to 'clock_getres'
libgomp.a(time.o): In function 'gomp_ialias_omp_get_wtime':
  undefined reference to 'clock_gettime'
```

While I don't have any error when I compile in 64bits (I made a simple test).

I use `-fopenmp` to link `openmp`. I tried to add `-gomp`, but it didn't change anything.

I'm running under a 2012 Cent OS release (64bits), and compiling with gcc 4.4.7.
And to make it more funny, I can't upgrade or install anything with `apt`, but I can compile from sources some missing libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older versions of glibc define `clock_getres` and `clock_gettime` in `librt`, not `libc`, so you probably just need to link with `-lrt`.